# JS Excel Export Code is removing ALL empty spaces from report content

Tags: javascript, php, export, xls

I am writing a JS code to export a dynamic collection of company reports. I've got the code to compile all the reports into one large excel document, but for some reason the exported file is removing ALL the spaces between every word, in every cell of the report.

I've echoed the compiled table before it's exported, and it looks just fine.

```
//Each report I'm compiling into one large table has the typical arrangement of: 

<table>
<thead> - <th> - </th> (dynamic number) </thead> 
<tbody> - <td> - </td> (dynamic number) - </tbody> 
</table>

function loadEXCEL(tableID){
    //Gather Data
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    //console.log(tableHTML);

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, thisFileName);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = thisFileName;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
  }
```

What would cause a Blob to remove all the spaces from every cell as it exports?

Again, I'm echoing the final massive table beforehand, and the spaces are there. I assume it's the fault of the Blob in some way, but I have no idea.

How to stop the exporting process from removing the spaces between every word?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and added it into a codepen with a sample data
https://codepen.io/konutis/pen/RwwmXwV?editors=1010

I have MacBook, so I can open this file only in the "Numbers" application.

And what I see there is this -

[image]

But I had a similar problem with the spaces when opening in Excel and there are no spaces.

I solved it with FileSaver.js plugin. It is a small opensource plugin which does all the saving for you.
Here is a library - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

All you need to do is to add this library and then just run this

```
const tableText = document.querySelector('yourTableSelectorHere').innerText;
saveAs(new Blob([tableText], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8'}), 'table.xls', true);
```

Note: tableText variable is inner text from your table (not HTML).

It helped for me, hope it helps for you too.
Here is a working example - https://codepen.io/konutis/pen/dyyEEbm